# Show grouped products without simple products in list page

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

We need to display grouped products without simple products associated with it in listing page. By default in Magento 2, if there is no simple product associated with grouped product then the grouped product doesn't show in product listing ,but we need to display grouped products without simple products associated with it. Can anyone done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$productFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()
    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
foreach ($productFactory as $product)
{
   $associatedProduct = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts();
   if(!isset($associatedProduct))
   {
       $productName = $product->getName();
   }
}
```

Comment: hii , thanks for the code but i need to modify product collection in list page so that i need to show grouped products without simple products.

Comment: you can override list.phtml file and apply filter to display grouped products without simple products

Comment: in magento 2.2.5 they are showing but from magento 2.2.6 the grouped without simple are not showing . Is there any path to debug that in collection level.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Comment: in this file load collection and display product